# How to plot a rotated parabola using ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, plot, extjs4, internet-explorer-9

I have to plot (something like) a rotated parabola using extjs charts (version 4.2.10).

I should draw something like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%20-%202xy%20%2B%20y%5E2%20-%20x%20*%20sqrt%282%29%20-%20y%20*%20sqrt%282%29%20%3D%200) (just the curve):

[image: a rotated parabola]

But at best I can get is [this (on jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/FGB4n/2/).

```
var chartDataStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.ArrayStore", {
    storeId: "chartData",
    fields: [
        { name: "x", type: "integer" },
        { name: "y", type: "integer" }
    ],
    data: [
        [10,14],
        [5,10],
        [2,6.3],
        [0,2],
        [2,1],
        [5,2]
    ]

});

var win = Ext.create("Ext.chart.Chart", {
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    hidden: false,
    title: "Example chart",
    renderTo: "demoChart",
    layout: "fit",
    style: "background:#fff",
        animate: true,
        store: chartDataStore,
        shadow: true,
        theme: "Category1",
        legend: {
            position: "bottom"
        },
        axes: [{
            type: "Numeric",
            minimum: 0,
            position: "left",
            fields: ["y"],
            title: "Y",
            minorTickSteps: 1,
            grid: {
                odd: {
                    opacity: 1,
                    fill: "#ddd",
                    stroke: "#bbb",
                    "stroke-width": 0.5
                }
            }
        }, {
            type: "Category",
            position: "bottom",
            fields: ["x"],
            title: "X"
        }],
        series: [{
            type: "line",
            highlight: {
                size: 7,
                radius: 7
            },
            axis: "left",
            smooth: true,
            xField: "x",
            yField: "y",
            title: "Rotated Parabola (not working)",
            markerConfig: {
                type: "cross",
                size: 4,
                radius: 4,
                "stroke-width": 0
            },
        }]

});
```

A collegue of mine suggested to use [Highchart for ExtJS](http://joekuan.org/) but we were not able to draw such plot. Note that the solution should run on **IE9**.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that such curve has two values of `y` to one value of `x` and that cannot be achieved with line chart.

One possibility would be to draw a straight parabola with Ext chart and then rotate the whole chart with [css transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp).

Comment: +1 This is a smart solution, but I forgot to say that I have to support IE9.

Comment: I don't use IE so I don't know what IE9 supports and what not but I believe that 9 is high enough to support some kind of transformations if not with css3 syntax then with a custom Microsoft syntax. Somebody else could advise on that.